# Deleting a calendar on Android using ContentResolver

Tags: android, database, google-calendar-api, android-contentprovider

So I messed up while playing with the **content://com.android.calendar/calendars** database on my phone. I managed to insert a new calendar with null as a displayName; and now my Calendar app is crashing on open saying "The display name can't be null".

So now I'm trying to delete that calendar but I'm stuck... Here is what I'm trying:

Here is the list of calendars in the DB

> INFO/System.out(4170): Id: 1 Display Name: myemail@gmail.com Selected: true
>   INFO/System.out(4170): Id: 3 Display Name: null Selected: true

And then I want to delete the second one so:

```
Uri cal = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
getContentResolver().delete(cal, "_id=?", new String[] {"3"});
```

Without success.... any ideas? It doesn't crash, but the query returns 0, meaning no rows have been deleted. Thanks in advance

Comment: This content provider is undocumented, unsupported, may not exist on all devices, and may not be available in future versions of Android. Please use the Google Calendar GData API for accessing a user's Google Calendar.

Comment: try `" _id =? "` instead of `"_id=?"`